Do we believe there’s 100% proof Hashem exists
Do we believe that (nowadays at least) there’s 100% proof that Hashem exists and it’s a mitzvah to go and discover that proof and “know” that there’s a G-d, or do we believe that, although many signs might point to it, there’s no actual 100% proof Hashem exists but rather we have faith that He does.
During let’s say the midbar times, when the people actually saw G-d, there you’d say that they had 100% proof. But nowadays, do we believe there’s 100% solid proof out there and that we must seek it out, or is our faith simply “blind faith”

Chovos haLevavos, Gate 1, sections 5-6 tried to bring the proofs, but it might not be sufficient for the modern standards of rigor.

@YDJ thanks I just briefly read it and yeah that was part of our debate. Basically we were debating whether proofs like that (that something can’t come from nothing) constitute 100% proof of Gd and it’s a mitzvah to rationalize them in your head, or whether they’re simply compelling proofs but not 100% and therefore we simply rely on blind faith

I think the 1st commandment interpreted as to know that there is Hashem shows there may not be 100% proof. Also the first Ani Maamin to be accepted on faith.

Hashem is all-powerful and fundamentally unfalsifiable. There is no proof that there is a Hashem, and (by dint of His omnipotent ability to create a world in any fashion) there is no proof that there is no Hashem. Our belief in Hashem is exclusively a choice, made exclusively on faith.

I don’t think one can “prove” God, if one chooses to believe they will, I’d not they won’t

Your question is a false dichotomy. The people of the midbar had 100% proof, so we have historical proof, which is far more than blind faith.

@YDJ According to almost all opinions, the first mitzvah is to know that Hashem exists based on the revelation at Sinai. According to many opinions, it includes an obligation to know intellectual proofs for Hashem's existence.

@N.T. well there is a difference between proofs. My proof includes my personal experience. But it is not universal. If it was everyone would be a believer. Nobody would be an evil doer.

@N.T. I also try to exclude proofs when I walked to shul on Shabbos and driving by people stopped by to express excitement and tell their kids that G-d exists because i was walking to shul.

Like most empirical questions, Judaism doesn't have an official position on this TTBOMK

@YDJ That is a non-sequitur.

@DoubleAA Look at any of the Rishonim who define the mitzvah of Anochi Hashem Elokecha.

@N.T. many rishonim had opinions, that doesn't mean Judaism has an official position

@DoubleAA It's a universal opinion among Rishonim and early Acharonim. That is by definition Judaism.

@N.T. geocentrism too. Interesting definition you've got there

@DoubleAA Geocentrism is not a halacha; it's a description of nature.

@N.T. Whether a proof exists is also a fact about nature.

@DoubleAA If there was a halacha to believe in geocentrism, then the halacha and Judaism would be wrong, ch"v.  As there is not, the opinions that were geocentric were wrong about a material fact, not Judaism. There is a halacha to believe Hashem exists, at a minimum from the historical evidence. This is universally agreed to, and spelled out clearly in Deuteronomy ch. 4-5. That is by definition Judaism. One who argues is disagreeing with Judaism at a fundamental level, and likely would have the halachic status of a heretic. See Mishneh Torah Laws of Repentance 3:7.

@N.T. Straw man. Stay focused. We're discussing if there is a proof, not if He exits

@N.T. Rambam defines that mitzva as "believe" not "know" (according to Abarbanel - who does clarify that we are ment to believe in that which we already know because of mechuyav hametzius) and Ramban agrees in his Hasagos. Halachos Gedolos doesn't even count it as a mitzva, and explains that the belief in God is something not commanded, but rather deduced from the signs and wonders He performed for our ancestors. The Zohar in Raya Mehemna Vayera 25a brings up the point about knowing and defines it more specifically etc.

@RabbiKaii https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.1.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

@N.T. we are discussing Mitzvot.

@RabbiKaii See also https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Hasagot_Ramban_Sefer_HaMitzvot_Forgotten_Negative_Commandments_1 Where Ramban says the Bahag has a negative commandment to not forget Hashem, which corresponds to Anochi. While there he uses the term Emunah, the Ramban writes at the end of his dispute with the Church (and also in his work Emunah uBitachon) that Emunah requires intellectual knowledge as a prerequisite.

@DoubleAA So is the Rambam. See Halacha 6. And see his listing of mitzvot in the beginning of the sefer: https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Rambam_Hilkhot_Yesodei_HaTorah_Introduction

@RabbiKaii In addition, see the Frankel edition of Rambam that the Rambam in Sefer Hamitzvos was mistranslated, and the Arabic word used by Rambam is more accurately translated as "to be convinced".

@DoubleAA Try reading what I wrote again. The proof is historical.

@N.T. I don't understand why you are telling me what kind of proof you propose to have (or what it means to have "kinds" of proofs). There either is or isn't a proof. I don't see anything in Halacha 6 about if there is or is not a proof, just that there is a Deity. He never says מצות עשה להאמין שיש דרך להוכיח במאה אחוז מציאת האלוה הזה.

I think this is a great question! Wouldn't 100% proof impinge on our free will?

@MosesSupposes thanks! That’s what I would assume, but a lot of these comments and answers don’t seem to address that

What is your definition of "proof"? What is an example of proof in mundane matters? Do you mean like in a court of law? In science?

The Rambam held that the 13 Articles of Faith needed to be accepted because of proofs. Not "believed", not accepted because you were taught them by an authority figure or read them in a book. But each person should be able to prove them for themselves. (Igeres Taiman)
R Chaim Heller noted in his translation of Sefer haMitzvos (1914) that the Rambam uses the Judeo-Arabic word "itakad", which means "knowledge". R Yosef el-Qafih, commonly known as Rav Kapach (of the Yemenite community) has a similar footnote in his translation (1994).
One could ascribe to the element of the Rambam's position that emunah is knowledge without agreeing to the facet of his position that you asked about -- that knowledge is most centrally something you can prove. At least, not in the sense of a philosophical proof.
Perhaps the most famous line in Epistemology is Plato's definition of "knowledge" as "a justified true belief." (That definition is flawed, most famously by the Gettier Problem, but it's still the basis of all such discussion.) There are other ways to justify belief than Philosophical Proof.
Before the Rambam, Rav Yehudah haLevi (Kuzari sec. 1) even belittles the entire concept of philosophically proving this kind of thing. In his dialog, he has the Rabbi say (1:13):

That which you describe is religion based on speculation and system, the research of thought, but open to many doubts. Now ask the philosophers, and thou will find that they do not agree on one set of actions or one principle, since some doctrines can be established by arguments, which are only partially satisfactory, and still much less capable of being proved.

And later in that section (1:63), he pardons the Greek philosophers for their errors in that they lacked a tradition and had to rely on a second-best -- philosophical deduction:

There is an excuse for the Philosophers. Being Grecians, science and religion did not come to them as inheritances. They belong to the descendants of Japheth, who inhabited the north, whilst that knowledge coming from Adam, and supported by the divine influence, is only to be found among the progeny of Shem, who represented the successors of Noah and constituted, as it were, his essence. This knowledge has always been connected with this essence, and will always remain so...

Skipping out of our tradition and ahead to Modern Philosophy...
This skepticism about the perfection of proof becomes fundamental to the Empiricists, who believed that only experience of the outside world can produce reliable knowledge. And then it really came to the fore with Immanuel Kant, who denied our ability to experience what's really "out there" altogether. That because everything we experience and think are shaped by pre-existing human categories, the way people work, none of it is real and objective. We only know the world of phenomena, how things look to humans, and only can reason with those more limited givens.
And this progresses through the Existentialists and the Post-Moderns. So that today, in most College Liberal Arts departments, there is no concept of objective truth altogether. Never mind being able to prove things.
I think the Kuzari's argument would be classified today as a kind of Reliabilism. We trust our Tradition because it comes from sources that have proved themselves reliable in the past. Which is a way to justify belief, so -- contrary to the Rambam -- today's philosophers would consider trusting a fact because you were taught it bey someone you trust would be considered knowledge.
Another possible justification could be first-hand experience. And I think this happens far more often today. Someone experiences their first Shabbos. It agrees with them, provides meaning to their lives. I don't just mean the aesthetics, that they enjoyed themselves, but the experience itself -- the thing they enjoyed. Like the way mathematicians are likely to agree on what makes a proof "beautiful" or "elegant", there is an objective feature they are identifying and giving an aethetic judgement about. That math proof, or living that Shabbos, has the features one expects of truth.
Or, when you learn something about the laws of property that somehow has implications in the laws of Shabbos and resolve what seemed to have been an unrelated question. Truth works like that, not invented systems. If this happens to someone when learning Torah often enough, they stop wondering whether or not they can prove the Torah is from Hashem. Or whether halakhah as we now practice it, which is largely a product of a system, is a product of the system Hashem gave us at Sinai. It seems obviously so.
The experience of living Judaism as justification for the givens assumed by the Judaism lived.
Speaking for myself. I do believe a philosophical proof does exist. But, just to frustrate the Rambam, I don't think we could identify it. We have too many of what Mussarists call "negi'os", personal ulterior motives, that color our vision. Our ideas of what is a self-evident given that could be used as a postulate for an argument start getting subjective as soon as we go much beyond "x = x". Similarly, our sense of which questions refute the whole argument or are interesting little side challenges that could be shelved for later. They all are so colored by what we want the answer to be that a person couldn't identify a solid argument for or against their position.
Not when dealing with something we are so emotionally invested in as a question that changes how we live our lives.
Or, to rephrase as a Truism:
The mind is a wonderful organ
for proving conclusions
the heart already reached.

What is the difference between this "proof" that you say the Rambam believes is the definition of belief (when you say "the 13 Articles of Faith needed to be accepted because of proofs") and the "philosophical proof" that you say the Rambam doesn't necessarily hold by? (The Rambam's definition of the term is by the way in More Nevuchim 1:50: דע, אתה המעיין במאמרי זה, כי ההאמנה אינה העניין הנאמר בפה, אבל העניין המצוייר בנפש, כשיאמינו בו שהוא כן כמו שיצוייר...)

If I said the Rambam didn't hold of the need for philosophical proof, there is a typo.somewhere. I did say that R Yehudah haLevi in the Kuzari says that one doesn't need philosophical proof and that they don't work anyway. and that this element of the Kuzari's thought is more consistent with modern philosophies. Even if we accept, like the Rambam, that we are to know and not just believe, there are justifications other than being able to build a philosophical argument.

You said (in the answer) "One could ascribe to the Rambam's position that emunah is knowledge without holding... that knowledge is... something you can prove... in the sense of a philosophical proof"; and (in your comment) "Even if we accept... the Rambam... there are justifications other than... philosophical argument." What is this non-philosophical proof or non-philosophical justification, or what would be an example of it, that fulfills the Rambam's understanding of believing in God?

I meant that the someone could agree with the Rambam that emunah means knowledge while disagreeing with him that philosophical proof is the only or even most sure way to gain knowledge. And that's why I then get into other ways of justifying belief, so that one's emunah is knowledge, not faith. I will try an edit. Please let me know if it is clearer now

Clear. But then, at the end of your answer you're arguing against what we just agreed is the view of the Rambam (or its applicability to us)? If the Rambam (I think also the Kuzari, in his way) says the mitzva is to believe in God by a specific kind of reasoning, on what basis do you say we can't? If because of biases, isn't overcoming biases part of the duty we would have anyway by any kind of view equating emuna with knowledge?

@ba: and overcoming our biases is necessary to make proper choices on behavioral decisions too. But the best way to change attitudes is experience as well. Much more emotionally impactful. But do you think it is possible for a person to be entirely without bias? The need for Yir'as Hashem is to become biased against violating Hashem's Will. (Which is why the Mesilas Yesharim says that the default "Yir'ah" in texts is "Yor'as haCheit" - not fear of punishment nor (directly) awe over Hashem's Greatness, but fear of the sin itself.

So, take a less all-or-nothing viewpoint. I don't think the all-or-nothing philosophical proof can exist only because I don't think people can ever be unbiased enough to be able to objectively assess that argument even if it happens to be one we know. But still, the strong but imperfect argument can be a valid notice to believe. If you have many such motives, a person can know there is a G-d even without a proof usable to convince someone else. My bit about knowledge justified by personal experience is also a justification you cannot simply share with someone else.

Even if you invite them to keep a Shabbos or learn Torah (to repeat my examples) there is no guarantee they will see in that experience what you do.

If you're speaking as a psychologist I accept, but if we're trying to make sense of the Rambam then you seem to be saying something very strange: First, that the Rambam said there's a mitzva to do something that turns out to be impossible for real people to do. Second, the reason you give why it's impossible is bias, which applies no less to any other possible interpretation of emuna (said not as an "all-or-nothing" viewpoint, but to suggest that the issue of bias is insufficient in itself to prefer a different interpretation of emuna).

The answer to the first point is (necessarily) either that there is a 100% proof available to people, or that there isn't but the Rambam meant the mitzva is something other than a 100% proof, or that the Rambam just makes no sense. Which of these three (if any) are you're trying to say? (The same question could be asked by replacing Rambam with Kuzari or anyone.) I ask with a view to see if you have a straight answer to the literal question as posed (not to imply any disrespect if you only mean to give a non-straight answer).

I am saying the Rambam, like all his contemporaries, had a different opinion of objective proofs than later emerged in philosophy. He and his contemporaries also didn't have the same opinion we do today about the role of non-conscious elements of our minds play in our decision making. That means that he defined Emunah in a way that isn't consistent with modern approaches to either philosophy or psychology. Further developments in these fields appear to have validated R Yehudah haLevi's skepticism about the power of philosophy. The Rambam "made sense" for his day, we just don't share his givens

@ba: And regardless of what the Rambam believed, we make life-and-death decisions all the time without "100% proof". So the fact that it turns out his goal now appears to be impossible isn't really relevant for the day-to-day. Saying that we can only know things if we have an airtight proof is setting a higher standard for this than we hold for anything else in life.

Since the issue is the mitzva of emuna and not day-to-day decision making, the standard I hold this to is simply that given by those who discuss emuna, not what's useful in decision making. In that light I pointed out reasons why this view is strange. Saying the Rambam (and Kuzari) made sense but don't make sense to us means the strangeness remains, for us. I'm inclined to think he wasn't as ignorant of the unconscious and bias as we might think (e.g. MN 1:5), or of what to us are developments in philosophy, even if he speaks differently; but maybe this veers too much from your thinking.

@ba What I am saying is that anything with strong enough justification that you'd base life and death decisions because you assume its truth is "known", not merely believed. This "100% proven" thing is not only impossible, it's not even a reasonable standard. (But again, this isn't how the world was seen n the Rambam's day.)

@ba, as for the Rambam's approach to the subconscious, ulterior motives, the frequency at which we fool ourselves about our own thought processes... The entire Moreh Nevuchim is based on the idea that correct thoughts lead to correct action. This is fundamental to his understanding Adam's sin in the opening chapters (1:1-1:2), to how he ranks perfections in the closing one (3:54). It shows in his description of how to become capable pf prophecy or Divine Providence (3:18). The other half of the cycle, the effects of middos on our ability to think clearly, doesn't show up once....

@ba, to the Rambam, emotions and aesthetic judgments are things that get in the way of being good. Not things you fix to fit the Torah's definition of good. This is the point of his presentation of Adam's sin in MN 1:1-2, that before the sin he was purely driven by truth, and now we're broken. Similarly (again, but it took me 3 weeks to notice this tab and finish this comment) the Rambam's ranking of human perfections in 3:54 -- he separates out Middos (or as he called it: Dei'os) work is a separate and lower concern.

@ba, it shows that the Rambam believes the ideal isn't fixing the unconscious, but rising above it. (And while emotions can be caused by unconscious thought, we are often conscious of.our emotions. Emotions aren't the same thing as midos / dei'os or negi'os.)

@ba yes. And... Because of this the Rbam bases his whole.project on intellect overcoming emotion, bias, aesthetics, etc... Whereas lat3r movements gave emphasis on fixing the Middos using things other than trying to outthink.them - in addition to thought. Mussar, for example, has both cognitive and behavioral modalities. And even the cognitive.... Learning behispaalus is learning with an eye to make it experiential and emotional.

Since this is becoming tangential to your answer I created a chat room here. I thought it would be useful to restate the argument to avoid being on a totally different track of thinking than you, so you can confirm or correct my understanding of what you meant (though of course no need to prolong the discussion any more than you want)

The Rambam in Hilchot Yesodei Hatora Chapter 1, Halacha 1 says
"יְסוֹד הַיְסוֹדוֹת וְעַמּוּד הַחָכְמוֹת לֵידַע שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם מָצוּי רִאשׁוֹן"  "The foundation of all foundations and the pillar of wisdom is to know that there is a Prime Cause"
Apparently the Rambam holds it is a Mitzvah to prove the existence of God.
The Rambam himself provides a demonstration from the science of his times to prove God.  Apparently he holds that in each time we would need to look to the physical world to reach a point in our understanding that would demonstrate the existence of  God.
Here is a link to modern approach to "prove" God.  https://www.physicstogod.com/
They do an excellent job of demonstrating a "proof" for the existence of God.

There is no proof that God exists, and there cannot be one.  It's 100% a matter of faith.  You can never be sure that what you see and experience is not the work of a powerful alien with super-advanced technology, who has no more answers to ultimate questions than we do.
Think how easy it would be to convince a primitive islander of 500 years ago that you are God.  You land in a helicopter, cure his sick with antibiotics, use a machine gun or a grenade to show him who is boss, magnify your voice with a loudspeaker, etc.

In Derech Hashem 3, he states that when one has a prophetic experience, it activates a center of the intellect that is reserved purely for prophesy, and when it happens it is completely crystal clear that it is really a prophesy and not a hallucination etc.

Maybe there is such a proof and it hasn't been discovered yet?

@DoubleAA How can one create a proof that covers every moment of human history? We do not have records for large periods of it. We already have difficulty of learning from all animals in the world, which used to fit inside Noah's Ark although you believe we can without explaining.

@YDJ I don't know. Maybe someone else will figure it out one day

@DoubleAA they could not figure it out with Temple and prophesy. Even in the desert they carried an idol of Micha. That's beyond reasonable.

@YDJ No one is talking about "reasonable".

@RabbiKaii -- None of what I described in my answer is a "hallucination".

@DoubleAA Chovos haLevavos gave reasonable proofs as I mentioned in the comments to the question, but the standards of rigor improved and it's no longer reasonable. There are proofs by intelligent design, due to very low probability that mutations of DNA yield a viable form of life, but they also can be interpreted like Maurice Mizrachi states via extra-terrestials. You are having a double standard to some answers vs. the others.

@YDJ the only standard is that people who post answers can defend and explain them. This answer asserts that something doesn't exist and offers no support for its claim.

@DoubleAA -- Go back and review Philosophy 101: You can't prove a negative and should not have to.

@Maurice you indeed can't prove a negative but you have to for this answer to be work. Crazy that someone who has been to PHI101 would think to post something so obviously undefendable

@DoubleAA -- What is this "negative" you want me to prove against all logic?  I never said there is no God.  I said belief in God is purely a matter of faith.  Mine too.  That's why we say Ani maamin be-emunah shelemah... -- I believe with perfect faith.  Do you read messages before downvoting or just go by the name of the author?

"There is no proof that God exists" First line in the post is a negative.

@MauriceMizrahi I apologise for using the wrong word, but my point stands regardless. Prophecy can't be mistaken

@RabbiK that's an unproven assumption

@DoubleAA I'm not trying to answer the question, but bringing something of interest and relevance

What is your definition of "proof"?
